# Use Get content or Import-CSV to read 1st column in 2nd line in a csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

So I have a csv file which is 25MB.
I only need to get the value stored in 2nd line in first column and use it later in powershell script.

e.g data

```
File_name,INVNUM,ID,XXX....850 columns
ABCD,123,090,xxxx.....850 columns
ABCD,120,091,xxxx.....850 columns
xxxxxx5000+ rows
```

So my first column data is always the same and i just need to get this filename form the first column, 2nd row.

Should I try to use Get-content or Import-csv for this use case ?

Thanks,
Mickey

Answer (score 3):

[TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737039/45375) contains a pragmatic, easy-to-understand solution that is most likely fast enough in practice; the same goes for [Robert Cotterman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738384/45375) which is concise (and also faster).

***If* performance is really paramount**, you can try the following, which **uses the .NET framework directly** to read the lines - but given that you only need to read *2* lines, it's probably not worth it:

```
$inputFile = "$PWD/some.csv" # be sure to specify a *full* path
$isFirstLine=$true
$fname = foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inputFile)) { 
  if ($isFirstLine) { $isFirstLine = $false; continue } # skip header line
  $line -replace '^([^,]*),.*', '$1' # extract 1st field from 2nd line and exit
  break # exit
}
```

Note: A conceptually simpler way to extract the 1st field is to use `($line -split ',')[0]`, but with a large number of columns the above `-replace`-based approach is measurably faster.

*Update*: [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) offers 2 ways to speed up the above:

- Use of `$line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf(','))` in lieu of `$line -replace '^([^,]*),.*', '$1'` in order to avoid relatively costly *regex* processing.
- To lesser gain, use of a `[System.IO.StreamReader]` instance's [`.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline) method twice in a row rather than [`[IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) in a loop.

Here's a **performance comparison of the approaches across all answers** on this page (as of this writing).

To run it yourself, you must download functions [`New-CsvSampleData`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/17aa040ab85391749af7cf5a57b6e11b) and [`Time-Command`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27) first.

For more representative results, the timings are averaged across 1,000 runs:

```
# Create sample CSV file 'test.csv' with 850 columns and 100 rows.
$testFileName = "test-$PID.csv"
New-CsvSampleData -Columns 850 -Count 100 | Set-Content $testFileName

# Compare the execution speed of the various approaches:
Time-Command -Count 1000 { 
    # Import-Csv
    Import-Csv -LiteralPath $testFileName | 
      Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 -ExpandProperty 'col1'
  }, {
    # ReadLines(), -replace
    $inputFile = $PWD.ProviderPath + "/$testFileName"
    $isFirstLine=$true
    foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inputFile)) { 
      if ($isFirstLine) { $isFirstLine = $false; continue } # skip header line
      $line -replace '^([^,]*),.*', '$1' # extract 1st field from 2nd line and exit
      break # exit
    }    
  }, {
    # ReadLines(), .Substring / IndexOf
    $inputFile = $PWD.ProviderPath + "/$testFileName"
    $isFirstLine=$true
    foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inputFile)) { 
      if ($isFirstLine) { $isFirstLine = $false; continue } # skip header line
      $line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf(',')) # extract 1st field from 2nd line and exit
      break # exit
    }    
  }, {
    # ReadLine() x 2, .Substring / IndexOf
    $inputFile = $PWD.ProviderPath + "/$testFileName"
    $f = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFile,$true); 
    $null = $f.ReadLine(); $line = $f.ReadLine()
    $line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf(','))
    $f.Close()
  }, {
    # Get-Content -Head, .Split()
    ((Get-Content $testFileName -Head 2)[1]).split(',')[1]
  } |
  Format-Table Factor, Timespan, Command

Remove-Item $testFileName
```

Sample output from a single-core Windows 10 VM running Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0-preview.4 on a recent-model MacBook Pro:

Windows PowerShell v5.1:

```
Factor TimeSpan         Command
------ --------         -------
1.00   00:00:00.0001922 # ReadLine() x 2, .Substring / IndexOf...
1.04   00:00:00.0002004 # ReadLines(), .Substring / IndexOf...
1.57   00:00:00.0003024 # ReadLines(), -replace...
3.25   00:00:00.0006245 # Get-Content -Head, .Split()...
25.83  00:00:00.0049661 # Import-Csv...
```

PowerShell Core 6.1.0-preview.4:

```
Factor TimeSpan         Command
------ --------         -------
1.00   00:00:00.0001858 # ReadLine() x 2, .Substring / IndexOf...
1.03   00:00:00.0001911 # ReadLines(), .Substring / IndexOf...
1.60   00:00:00.0002977 # ReadLines(), -replace...
3.30   00:00:00.0006132 # Get-Content -Head, .Split()...
27.54  00:00:00.0051174 # Import-Csv...
```

**Conclusions:**

- Calling `.ReadLine()` twice is marginally faster than  the `::ReadLines()` loop.
- Using `-replace` instead of `Substring()` / `IndexOf()` adds about 60% execution time.
- Using `Get-Content` is more than 3 times slower.
- Using `Import-Csv | Select-Object` is close to 30 times(!) slower, presumably due to the large number of columns; that said, in absolute terms we're still only talking about around 5 milliseconds.
- As a side note: execution on macOS seems to be noticeably slower overall, with the regex solution and the cmdlet calls also being slower in relative terms.

Comment: Testing with `Measure-Command`; my `Import-Csv` code is very consistently around 1-2ms. Your code started off being around 44ms but then sometimes drops to 0.7 - 1.7ms and is faster, but sometimes isn't.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: With such short-running commands, you need to average the timings across many runs to get a true sense of relative performance. I've added timings for all commands on this page (including the `.ReadLine()` x 2 approach you propose) to the answer, some of which may be surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to prioritize.

```
$data = Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\data.csv' | 
            Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 -ExpandProperty 'File_Name'
```

Is short and convenient. (2nd line meaning 2nd line of the file, or 2nd line of the data? Don't skip any if it's the first line of data).

Select-Object with something like `-First 1` will break the whole pipeline when it's done, so it won't wait to read the rest of the 25MB in the background before returning.

You could likely speed it up, or reduce memory use, a miniscule amount if you opened the file, seek'd two newlines, then a comma, then read to another comma, or some other long detailed code, but I very much doubt it would be worth it.

Same with `Get-Content`, the way it adds `NoteProperties` to the output strings will mean it's likely no easier on memory and not usefully faster than `Import-Csv`

Comment: Yeah I meant second line of the file. Since first one is just headers. Also did want to load only first 2 lines read the file name from second one and then just return back control instead of trying to load all 25MB worth of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could really shorten it with

```
(gc c:\file.txt -head 2)[1]
```

Only reads 2 lines and then grabs index 1 (second line)

You could then split it.  And grab index 1 of the split up line

```
((gc c:\file.txt -head 2)[1]).split(',')[1]
```

UPDATE:::After seeing the [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737892/10035141) with times, I was inspired to do some tests myself (Thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)). this was the fastest I could get to work

```
$check = 0
foreach ($i in [IO.FILE]::ReadLines("$filePath")){
    if ($check -eq 2){break}
    if ($check -eq 1){$value = $i.split(',')[1]}  #$value = your answer
    $check++
}
```

Just thought of this: remove if -eq 2 and put `break` after a semi colon after the check 1 is performed. 5 ticks faster. Haven't tested.

here were my results over 40000 tests:

- GC split avg was 1.11307622 Milliseconds
- GC split Min was 0.3076 Milliseconds
- GC split Max was 18.1514 Milliseconds
- ReadLines split avg was 0.3836625825 Milliseconds
- ReadLines split Min was 0.2309 Milliseconds
- ReadLines split Max was 31.7407 Milliseconds
- Stream Reader avg was 0.4464924825 Milliseconds
- Stream Reader MIN was 0.2703 Milliseconds
- Stream Reader Max was 31.4991 Milliseconds
- Import-CSV avg was 1.32440485 Milliseconds
- Import-CSV MIN was 0.2875 Milliseconds
- Import-CSV Max was 103.1694 Milliseconds

I was able to run 3000 tests a second on the 2nd and 3rd, and 1000 tests a second on the first and last. **Stream Reader** was HIS fastest one. And import CSV wasn't bad, i wonder if the mklement0 didn't have a column named "file_name" in his test csv? Anyhow, I'd personally use the GC command because it's concise and easy to remember. But this is up to you, and I wish you luck on your scripting adventures.

I'm certain we could start hyperthreading this and get insane results, but when you're talking thousandths of a second is it really a big deal? Especially to get one variable? :D

here's the streamreader code I used for transparency reasons...

```
$inputFile = "$filePath"
$f = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFile,$true); 
$null = $f.ReadLine(); $line = $f.ReadLine()
$line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf(','))
$f.Close()
```

I also noticed this pulls the 1st value of the second line, and I have no idea how to switch it to the 2nd value... it seems to be measuring the width from point 0 to the first comma, and then cutting that. if you change substring from 0 to say 5, it still measures the length of 0 to comma, but then moves where to start grabbing... to the 6th character.

The import-csv I used was :

```
$data = Import-Csv -LiteralPath "$filePath" | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 -ExpandProperty 'FileName'
```

I tested these on a 90 meg csv, with 21 columns, and 284k rows. and "FileName" was the second column

Comment: The reason that `Import-Csv` was so slow in my tests is that the input file has 850 columns, as in the OP's case. The `Substring()` / `IndexOf()` approach works with the _first_ column only, because the extraction starts at the first character position (the start of the line); for any other you'd have first determine that column's starting position and use that as the starting point for both `Substring()` and `IndexOf`.